# WebAPI async method error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task-parallel-library

As you can see in the below code, i am getting the following two errors when I try to call the method asynchronously from Data Layer.

How can i call the method asynchronously without getting these errors?

> - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' is not defined or
> - imported Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are
>     you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to
>     an assembly?

*APIProject.DAL*

```
public class Account : BaseLayer
{
    public static Result SignIn(string userName, string userPass)
    {
        var inputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        inputParameters.Add("IN_USERNAME", userName);
        inputParameters.Add("IN_USERPASS", userPass);
        var response = ListStoredProcedure(Procedure.SignIn, inputParameters);
        var resultSet = new List<User>();
        foreach (DataRow row in response.DataTable.Rows)
        {
            resultSet.Add(new User
            {
                UserId   = row.GetVarchar("USERID"),
                Fullname = row.GetVarchar("FULLNAME")
            });
        }
        return new Result
        {
            HasResult = response.HasResult,
            Message   = response.Message,
            ResultSet = resultSet
        };
    }
}
```

*APIProject.WebAPI*

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<Result> SignIn(LogInModel model)
    {
        Result r = APIProject.DAL.Account.SignIn(model.UserName, model.UserPass);
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew<Result>(() => r);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `async` in your code as it is now, it doesn't achieve anything. It's async 'because you can'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code targets an old .NET Framework version. You need to target at least .NET 4.5. If you don't want to retarget your project, you can install the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package, which allows using `async\await` in older versions of .NET.

Comment: Thanks, your right its working finely when i change framework version as 4.5. Also i  want to ask a question about my code aproaching. Is it right way for asynchronous method?

Comment: No, what you're doing is a bad practice. You won't benefit after wrapping `SignIn()` up into a `Task` in ASP.NET. Moreover, it's very likely that the code will be even slower due to unnecessary context switching. Unlike WPF, in ASP.NET you should use `async\await` only for I\O operations, such as sending\receiving data over the internet, reading\writing files or accessing a DB.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your project to .NET 4.5 or higher, ***and*** [set `httpRuntime.targetFramework` in your `web.config` to the appropriate value](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/).

If you skip this second step, `async`/`await` will *compile*, but may not work properly.

Comment: Thanks, i already inpected your web page in today when i search resource  about async WebAPI :)

Answer (score 1):

You get the error

> ‘System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine’ is not defined or
>   imported

when you target the wrong .NET framework version. For async to work out of the box you need to target your application to .NET 4.5 (at the minimum)

Comment: thank, i have just change to framework version as 4.5. it works finely.